# Regex that stops on concatenated strings?

Tags: regex

So, I have a for each that goes through all of our pages' Regex.Matches for manipulation... The problem is that I can't seem to correctly create a regex for certain strings. The goal is essentially to grab:

> [ControlName].Text = "Static ""Text"" Here!"

As shown below, I'm able to do so... However, I'm getting issue when it comes to concatenated strings, I'd like to stop matching after the final closing quotation mark *before* concatenation. (see Goals below)

Current Regex: `\w+\.Text = (".*?"+?.*"?)`

Currently Hits:

- `lblError.Text = "Error on: ""Navigation Admin"" page."`
- `lblError.Text = "Error on:" & "Navigation Admin"`
- `lblError.Text = "Error on:" & ""Navigation Admin"" page."`

Goal:

- `lblError.Text = "Error on: ""Navigation Admin"" page."`
- `lblError.Text = "Error on:"` & "Navigation Admin"
- `lblError.Text = "Error on:"` & ""Navigation Admin"" page."

I'm quite possibly underthinking this, overthinking this and/or horrible at regexes in general. Any advice/tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way to match a quoted string including escaped quotes (2 consecutive quotes):

```
\w+\.Text = ("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, That works flawlessly! I should have delved more into grouping.